# Sub locations (Rack/Tray/Position)

Tags: acumatica

We currently have a small number of Acumatica locations set up which are largely functional rather than physical.  (Inbound Testing, Stockroom, RMA Review, etc).

We use these to set default issue/receipt locations and other such things.

We are also interested in tracking physical locations for our serialized parts. (We would use a rack/tray/position system, with each rack holding multiple trays and position on a tray being specific to a single serial number.)

Does Acumatica have any built-in functionality to support this kind of thing, or to get us further along the path?  We don't want to end up with 40,000 individual locations. If we need to add customizations, are there suggestions for how and where to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per discussion with Acumatica (thanks, Ruslan!) we have confirmed that there is no default functionality for what we're trying to do, and customization is required.

He suggested if each serialized item has its own location, we could extend the  INItemLotSerial table to track this.